# Where should I place new line sequence (/n) in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, substring, escaping

I start learning Python and am doing some exercises with escape sequences. I want to print variable values by adding some more text and do it in two lines.
e.g. John tells Harry,
"I got your gift".

my code is:

```
person1="john"
person2="Harry"
print(f"{person1.title()} tells {person2}," + "/nI got your gift")
```

But it doesn't print the second part in a new line. Where should I place /n in this code?

Comment: Please change '/n' to '\n'.

Comment: My carelessness :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\n` instead `/n` :)

```py
person1="john"
person2="Harry"
print(f"{person1.title()} tells {person2}," + "\n I got your gift")
```